# DKMS cannot find kernel headers

Tags: drivers, kernel, dkms

I am trying to install drivers for my TP-LINK wireless adapter. When trying to install the module and adding dkms I get this error:
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.0.0-32-generic cannot be found.
Using the option --kernelsourcedir doesnt help.
When going into /lib/modules my build shows like this:
build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic.

Comment: Try just installing the headers for the current kernel.  `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`